# Why does assigning a background color to a control override the style trigger?

Tags: wpf

I've got a simple WPF window with a label. There is a default style in the window that changes the label background to red when a mouse is over the label. Pretty simple.

This works, as long as I don't set/modify the labels color to anything, anywhere.

- If I set the labels background in code behind (via the 'Set Label Background' button in the code below) the style trigger stops working
- If I set the labels background in XAML (not shown, but an easy edit) the style does not work.
- If, after setting the labels color in code behind, I try to revert the background to what it was (whether null or transparent), the trigger goes from working, to not working.

I don't understand why setting the background seems to override the style.

What I'd prefer this to do is to keep the style active regardless of what background I set for the label - If I move the mouse over, it should change colors to red, regardless of if I've set it to blue or anything else. I'm OK if I have to create the trigger in code behind.

Instead, it seems like merely by assigning a background color to the label, I overwrite the style.

Here is the XAML :

```
    <Grid Background="Black">   
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,10,10,10" Height="75" Click="Button_Set_Click">Set Label Background</Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,10,10,10" Height="75" Click="Button_Clear_Click">Clear Label Background</Button>
    <Label Name="TestLabel" Grid.Row="2"  Margin="10,10,10,10" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="5"></Label>
    </Grid>
```

Here is the code behind :

```
public partial class WpfProblems : Window
{
    public WpfProblems()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Clear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // revert the label background color - I've tried setting to null, transparent also
        // but the trigger never comes back. 
        TestLabel.Background = (Brush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#00FFFFFF");            
    }

    private void Button_Set_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Set the label background color
        TestLabel.Background = Brushes.Blue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

By assigning a color to your Label, you are overwriting its Color property (which previously held the binding). So in the end you are breaking the binding by directly assigning the color either in code behind or in the xaml.

To fix the propblem you have to assign the default color in the style of your label so that the color is retained once the trigger condition is finished.

Lets say your style looks like below. Please notice how I am setting the default color for the label above the triggers section.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
<Style.Triggers>
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Red/>
</Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

**EDIT -**

Since you are using Code Behind files I think you can use DependencyProperty to control the color of the label. I tried this on a test app and it works.

Create a dependencyProperty as below. Notice the default color is blue as in your test app.

```
public Brush BackgroundColor
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(BackgroundColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BackgroundColorProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for BackgroundColor.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundColorProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("BackgroundColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.Blue));
```

Now your button click events will become

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundColor = Brushes.Yellow;
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundColor = Brushes.Blue;
        }
```

In the mainwindow (or your usercontrol) I have defined the following style for a label

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding BackgroundColor}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>



<Grid Background="Black">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,10,10,10" Height="75" Click="Button_Click">Set Label Background</Button>
            <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,10,10,10" Height="75" Click="Button_Click_1">Clear Label Background</Button>
            <Label Name="TestLabel"  Grid.Row="2"  Margin="10,10,10,10" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="5"></Label>
        </Grid>
```

And I am using the same grid that you have posted

Make sure you are settings the datacontext of the control properly in the code behind for this to work. Now the original style is retained even after you click any of the buttons.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: See [Dependency Property Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx) for an explanation why you "break the binding".

Comment: This helps. Is it possible to have N different styles like this and just pick one in code behind? Alternately, I may just just scrap the idea of setting the color on XAML IsMouseOver trigger, and just handle everything in code behind using mouse enter / mouse exit.

Comment: If you want to assign style in the code behind you can always use FindResource to find the style from your resource dictionary and assign it manually to the label. I wouldnt recommend it, but you can do it. Syntax - TestLabel.Style = (Style)FindResource("Style2");

Comment: Please see my edit using DependencyProperty and let me know if it solves your problem

Answer (score 1):

`DependencyProperty`s can be set from a number of different sources. For example, they can be set in `Style`s, in `Animation`s, in `Trigger`s, etc. Therefore, Microsoft determined that some of these update sources were more important then others and so should have precedence over others.

For example, a `Setter` inside a `Trigger` should have more precedence than a normal `Style Setter`, because otherwise, `Trigger`s just wouldn't work.

> What I'd prefer this to do is to keep the style active regardless of what background I set for the label

Clearly, depending on how you set the `Background`, this may not work... a simple property setting in code will always override properties set in a `Style`.

To find out more, please read the [Dependency Property Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.